# How can I get the text between <span></span> using Selenium importing webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[image]

- I tried using `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Hello Bot)]")`, but no luck!
- I am trying to make a whatsapp bot that takes another user's input as information which is why I want it so that when "Hello Bot" is stated, it initializes the bot

Comment: Please post the HTML code instead of screenshot

Comment: Also what error you have got ? for above code you have shared it will try to search a span with text 'Hello BOT', but in span you shared in snippet (Not a good idea) , inner text is Rscrap. SO not sure what exactly you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are viewing page source you can right click on `span` and select `Copy > Copy full XPath`, then paste it into your code.